# Browser can't load SBAs static resources (http instead of https)

Tags: spring-boot-admin

I deployed Spring-Boot-Admin on a Kubernetes cluster where it get's accessed via TLS/HTTPS. The problem is, that the SBA-frontend seems to load it's static resources via http instead of https. This is blocked by the browser:

[image]

Locally, everything works as it should. In fact, the resources are reachable via https (I can verify this by double-clicking on a failed request where it just loads fine).

The problem seems, that SBA sets a base path with 'http' prefix instead of 'https'?

[image]

So how can I force the frontend to load it's static resources via HTTPS, if available?

PS: I already set `server.use-forward-headers: true`, but that didn't change anything...

Answer (score 1):

Was able to resolve this by setting the following spring properties:

```
  forward-headers-strategy: framework # 'native' may work also
  use-forward-headers: true
```